# Decal Projector equivalent in unity's standard shader pipeline

Tags: unity, shaders, rendering, projection, decal-system

I have a script in my Unity project that creates glowing outlines around objects when highlighted in a scene. The shaders don't work properly with the URP or HDRP. However, I want to create a move target object for a point and click interface that will "paint" itself onto the environment where the player is going to move. Since this is a constantly changing dynamic placement, I figured the HDRP's decal projector would be the best way to do it.

Is there any kind of Decal Projector equivalent available in Unity's standard shader pipeline?

Comment: When you say "standard shader pipeline" do you mean the legacy/built-in renderer? [There's a projector component that works there](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Projector.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't know about the [Projector component](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Projector.html), thanks DMGregory.

Comment: Bear in mind that this re-renders every piece of geometry the decal projects onto. So if you have a giant terrain mesh with 5 decals on it, that whole mesh gets drawn at least 6 times - once for its base colour (maybe more for forward lighting), and again for every decal touching it. If that's a performance sink for your use case, you can also implement a deferred decal using the depth map.